# Can we merge two video in AVFoundation for implementing pause and play feature functionality

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, avfoundation, avassetwriter

Can we merge two video for implementing pause/play feature in screen recording type application in cocoa.

I did't write code yet. Because first I want to be conform about it that this can be possible.

First start video recording on pressing "Play Button" than stop its session by pressing  "pause Button" save its session AVCaptureSession into  AVCaptureMovieFileOutput in a temporary directory.

On tapping "Resume Button" again session will be started now pressing "Stop Button"
video save in temporary folder, then merge both video into single one and show it

Is it a right way of implementing pause/play functionality.If you have any other logic please share with me .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. Store captured samples in [NSTemporaryDirectory](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/NSTemporaryDirectory) and use [AVMutableComposition](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVMutableComposition_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to merge assets at the end of recording session.

Comment: Thanks for the response did you implement such a things can you provide me some sample code

Comment: I can't show you my code, 'cause it's under NDA. But i will do some samples of "general idea". Not right now though, too busy.

Comment: i am telling you give me whole code please you can give only merging video i am so troubled now a day i spent a couple of week on researching on it. If it is possible please give me a positive response